# What are "soft wrap opportunities introduced by the word break"?

Tags: css, overflow

I'm reading the documentation of the [CSS's overflow-wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap) property.

In particular, the value `anywhere` is documented as:

> To prevent overflow, an otherwise unbreakable string of characters — like a long word or URL — may be broken at any point if there are no otherwise-acceptable break points in the line. No hyphenation character is inserted at the break point. **Soft wrap opportunities introduced by the word break are considered when calculating min-content intrinsic sizes.**

While the value `break-word` is documented as:

> The same as the anywhere value, with normally unbreakable words allowed to be broken at arbitrary points if there are no otherwise acceptable break points in the line, **but soft wrap opportunities introduced by the word break are NOT considered when calculating min-content intrinsic sizes.**

But I don't know what are "soft wrap opportunities introduced by the word break" and what "min-content intrinsic sizes" are, so I cannot get the difference between those two values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differences between `normal`, `break-word` and `anywhere` are only clear if you are using `width: min-content` on the element containing the text, **and** you also set a `max-width`. A pretty rare scenario.

```css
div {
  width: min-content;
  max-width: 10em;
  background-color: #8ca0ff;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.d2 {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

.d3 span {
  overflow-wrap: anywhere;
}

.d4 {
  overflow-wrap: anywhere;
}
```

```html
<p>overflow-wrap: normal;</p>
<div class="d1">My sister was recently diagnosed with <span>pseudopseudohypoparathyroidism</span></div>

<p>overflow-wrap: break-word;</p>
<div class="d2">My sister was recently diagnosed with <span>pseudopseudohypoparathyroidism</span></div>

<p>overflow-wrap: anywhere; (on long word only)</p>
<div class="d3">My sister was recently diagnosed with <span>pseudopseudohypoparathyroidism</span></div>

<p>overflow-wrap: anywhere; (on entire element)</p>
<div class="d4">My sister was recently diagnosed with <span>pseudopseudohypoparathyroidism</span></div>
```